# Regex- Extract a text that is between 1 and 8 chars and does not contain more than 2 letters ([A-Za-z])

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I would like to extract a text using Regex that is between 1 and 8 chars and does not contain more than 2 letters ([A-Za-z]).

For example:

```
Valid: "12A-32B" from the text "Register:12A-32B Index:A"
Invalid: "12 Index" from the text "Register:12 Index:A"
```

In this example, the extracted text should have the text "Register" as a boundary.

I tried using positive/negative lookahead but to no avail.

Thank you.

Comment: From `Register:12A-32B Index:A` - why shouldn't e.g. `er:12`, or `32B I`?   And why not `r:12 I` from the second? I assume it has to do with word boundaries (**but that's not stated in the question**). Going on: `:12 ` in the second? `:A` from the same? Why not those?

Comment: I edited the question stating the regex boundary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^(?!.*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z])[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,8}$
```

This will match any string containing at most 8 numbers or letters, with a maximum of 2 letters appearing in the string.

You may need an additional step to extract the text inside your original text.  You could try using this regex:

```
Register:(.*) Index
```

We could try using a single regex for everything, but it would be complicated.  And it might be easier to just use two steps from your app layer.

## Demo

Comment: @ClasG I updated my answer to allow hyphen in addition to letters and numbers (aside from what is forbidden from the assertion).

Comment: Thank you for helping me

Comment: @Daniel Not a problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

1. Extract the text using the Register start delimiter
2. Use this regex with the extracted text:

   ```
   ^(.{1,8}?)(?<![A-Za-z]{3})( |$)
   ```